# Dynamically changing markers through local xml data

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

Am to get dynamically changing marker in google API through xml data, getting data from xml, si i have used set time interval to get dynamic effect...

something went wrong....

Please take look on below link and please suggest me:

[jsBin link](http://jsbin.com/mikol/2/edit)

Here is my complete code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_JQJz_Xyi5SP2IyMTzLQPjRz4l5Bh6FA&sensor=true">
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
var contentString = html;

var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
shadow: shadow,
icon: image,
zIndex: 1
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.432713,-70.317993),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});

setInterval(function() { 
downloadUrl("api.xml", function(doc) {

var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);

var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));

var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

var html = "<strong>Taxi Arica</strong></br><strong>Latitud:</strong> " + markers[i].getAttribute("lat") + "</br><strong>Longitud:</strong> " +  markers[i].getAttribute("lng");

var marker = createMarker(point,html);

}

});

},5000);
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)}); 
  </script>
```

api.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <marker>lat: "13.02378651", lng: "80.17517885"</marker>
</CD>
<CD>
    <marker>lat: "13.06907", lng: "80.22546"</marker>
</CD>
<CD>
    <marker>lat: "13.06105", lng: "80.25451"</marker>
</CD>
<CD>
    <marker>lat: "13.05616", lng: "80.24248"</marker>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Can you add your JS code to your question too, as well as the jsBin link, please?

Comment: What's going on here with the [bitwise shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7f48wx9%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)? `z-index: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5`

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**: The Google Marker Options don't allow for a `z-index` attribute.  Instead it should be called `zIndex`.

See the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

This should result in something like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  map: map,
  shadow: shadow,
  icon: image,
  zIndex: 1
});
```

**Secondly**: you're trying to access the lat and lng values in your XML like so:

```
var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
```

Your XML doesn't have any `lat` *attribute* on it like this:

```
<marker>lat: "13.02378651", lng: "80.17517885"</marker>
```

Instead your XML would need to look like this, for that javascript to work:

```
<marker lat="13.02378651" lng="80.17517885"></marker>
```

You probably need to go back to the drawing board and either rewrite your XML or work out a different way of parsing your XML.  Right now you'd probably need to use a regular expression to isolate the lat and lng parts of this string `lat: "13.02378651", lng: "80.17517885"`

The best way would probably be to create new XML nodes for each of the lat and lng values, something like:

```
<marker>
    <lat>13.02378651</lat>
    <lng>80.17517885</lng>
</marker>
```

Or:

```
<marker>
    <value name="lat">13.02378651</value>
    <value name="lng">80.17517885</value>
</marker>
```

Comment: I have mentioned JS code in JS Bin link, which i have mentioned in the question.. please take review and advice on this...

Comment: Once again am pasting js bin link for your easy review

Please take look at this: http://jsbin.com/mikol/2/edit,

Please suggest?

Comment: Don't just link to an external site.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Specifically it states _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."_

Comment: Thanks for the information on posting queries, 

Here is my complete code for your reference,

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback, will workout this and will get back to your in case of any suggestions needed...